# Change Data Capture Tracking all changes in fields even though its assigned for only few fields in Dynamics ax table

Tags: sql, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, cdc, change-data-capture

I have enabled change data capture for 5 fields in a table which is having 10 fields for Dynamics ax database

In those 5 fields i have modifiedBy field is available. So whenever i change a field in that 10 fields modifiedBy will be changing and its tracking it in CDC tables. 
But i dont want to track the changes in CDC tables if there is a change made in other 5 fields which are not tracked.

ex: Table1

```
A B C D E F G H I J(MODIFIEDBY)
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
8 6 4 3 2 4 5 6 7 8
```

I am tracking  G,H,I,J,F. 
But J is modifiedBy field which changes everytime you make changes in any of nine fields.
So if you make a change in field A , J will update so CDC capture the transaction. 
Which i dont want to track.

Can you please suggest me some solution for this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field `ModifiedBy` is updated by the system each time a record is updated, irrespective which field is changed.

So you must either:

- stop the data capture of the field `ModifiedBy`

or:

- create your own field which is updated when the 5 fields are updated, say `SomeFieldsModifiedBy`

The update of this field is trivial:

```
public void update()
{
    if (this.G != this.orig().G || this.H != this.orig().H || ...)
        this.SomeFieldsModifiedBy = curUserId();
    super();
}
```

Also consider updating the field on insert.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the reply. You are right that we can do like this. But this is almost similar to database logging which is causing some performance overhead. We are planning reduce performace overhead on ax so thats the reason why we are choosing CDC. Is there any other options ?????

Comment: You could disable the CreatedBy property on the table.

Comment: Hi Jan, Thanks for the reply. I accept that this is the solution to achieve what i asked. But we are looking for any other solutions other than this. Because this looks just similar to enabling database logging in ax which causes performance overhead. Do we have any other solutions other than creating new field and writing code and updating that field and tracking it.

Comment: I disagree that creating a new field  for a dedicated purpose resembles database logging. Also the overhead is neglectable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jan. Actually we have more tables which needs this to be done. So we need to do it in all those tables. Then i came to know this is similar way database logging is also working. I have seen many posts which says database logging is performance overhead.

Comment: Adding a field is not similar to database logging. You are left with the two options in the answer.

Comment: Once again i will test those scenarios and will update. Thanks .